# JavaFX: Service and GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, java-8

For a school project, I am programming a little Visualization for a PLC. Therefore I have a mySQL Database which has all the Information. Currently, when I click on a Button the program connects to the Database and gets it Information in an ArrayList. Then it checks the information in the ArrayList and puts Data in a ListView.

The problem is, that I want to let the program do that in a Service. As I said the GUI depends on the ArrayList. And I can't change the GUI in the service because then this Exception appears

```
  Sep 02, 2016 9:19:02 PM javafx.concurrent.Service lambda$static$488
WARNING: Uncaught throwable in javafx concurrent thread pool
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Unknown Source)
    at application.Controller$1$1.call(Controller.java:290)
    at application.Controller$1$1.call(Controller.java:1)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$null$493(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$executeTask$494(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My first Idea was to extract only the SQL stuff in the Service and then get the Data via the Method

```
service.getValue();
```

But the problem with this is that I don't know when the Service is finished to get the Data, because currently, the data is null.

Comment: This exception happens when multiple Threads are trying to modify the same List.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you want to run some process and return some value,
Of course `Service` nails it. This is how I go about my case and it works perfectly.

```
Service process = new Service() {
    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        return new Task() {
            @Override
            protected ObjectX call() throws Exception {

                updateMessage("Some message that may change with execution");
                updateProgress( workDone, totalWork ); 
                return ObjectX;
            }
        };
    }
};

process.setOnSucceeded( e -> {

    ObjectX processValue = (ObjectX)process.getValue();

    // TODO, . . . 
    // You can modify any GUI element from here...
    // ...with the values you got from the service
});

process.start();
```

**THINGS TO NOTE**

1. inner method `protected ObjectX call()` can return any type of object. Just make sure its an object and not a primitive type. You can go as far as populate some GUI elements inside this process and return it as an object, eg. `protected VBox call()`  . . . . `return my_vbox;`
2. `ObjectX processValue = (ObjectX)processList.getValue();` => You should cast the value you got from the `Service` back to the Object you want to use.
   If is just `Object`, you may not have to. But I doubt if you will ever have to use just `Object`.
3. also see `processList.setOnFailed()`, `processList.setOnRunning()`, `processList.setOnCancelled()`, `processList.setOnScheduled()`,
4. You can also bind some GUI elements to some Thread properties like this

   ```
   label.textProperty.bind( process.messageProperty ); // messageProperty is a StringProperty
   progressBar.progressProperty.bind( process.progressProperty )
   ```
5. make sure all the methods to further enhance your process have been created and initiated before calling the `process.start()`; Nothing happens until you have started the process.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your Help it helped a lot

Comment: Is there a Method to update the progress from another class, because I do all the SQL stuff in an external class and would like to update from there.

Comment: I think you shouldn't. I tried it, and its really messed up. You may consider doing this . . . that external class that does the **sql** **stuff** should just return some status (which the Service passes on to its inner method `updateValue(Object)`), then you can use the status you got from `ObjectX processValue = (ObjectX)processList.getValue();` to update your ui

Answer (score 2):

The `Service` class provides methods so you know if it has been **cancelled,succeded or failed**.

In the Constructor of your Class which extends Service use these methods :

```
        // succeeded?
        this.setOnSucceeded(s -> {
            // ...
        });

        // failed
        this.setOnFailed(f -> {
            // ...
        });

        // cancelled?
        this.setOnCancelled(c -> {
            // ...
        });
```

Also remember to use `updateProgress(current,maximum)`;  so you know what is happening during it's execution.

Here is a full example:

```
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class ExampleService extends Service<Boolean> {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public ExampleService() {

        // succeeded?
        this.setOnSucceeded(s -> {
            // ...
        });

        // failed
        this.setOnFailed(f -> {
            // ...
        });

        // cancelled?
        this.setOnCancelled(c -> {
            // ...
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Boolean> createTask() {
        return new Task<Boolean>(){

            @Override
            protected Boolean call() throws Exception {

                boolean result = false;


                //your code
                //.......
                //updateProgress(current,total)

                return result;
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: @Torben :) glad to hear