# JavaFX Service not succeeding

Tags: service, task, fxml

I'm trying to find the JavaFX equivalent of `SwingWorker` and `Service` class comes very close to it. I'm trying to load images in `ImageView()` using background task, and when the task succeeds, the Button `appMode` will use the `ImageView` as icon. But my problem is, the service class is always set on `SCHEDULED`, preventing the `setOnSucceeded()` to run. (I took the code for Service from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299724/javafx-service-and-gui)

```java
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

@FXML
private ToggleButton appMode;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
    Service<Boolean> process=new Service<>(){
        @Override
        protected Task<Boolean> createTask<>(){
            return new Task<>(){
                @Override
                protected Boolean call(){
                    Boolean val=false;
                    try{
                        light=new ImageView();
                        lightImg=new Image(App.class.getResourceAsStream("iconindicators/light.png"));
                        light.setImage(lightImg);
                        val=true;
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }
                    return val;
                }
            };
        }
    };
    process.setOnSucceeded(e->{
        if(process.getValue()){
            appMode.setGraphic(light);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Failed.");
        }
    });
    process.start();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The [`Image` constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,boolean)) has a `backgroundLoading` flag you can set.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I don't need `Service`, rather the `Task` will suffice:

```java
Task<Boolean>work=new Task<>(){
    @Override
    protected Boolean call(){
        Boolean done=false;
        try{
            light=new javafx.scene.image.ImageView();
            lightImg=new javafx.scene.image.Image(App.class.getResourceAsStream("iconindicators/light.png"));
            light.setImage(lightImg);
            done=true;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return done;
    }
};
new Thread(work).start();
work.setOnSucceeded(e->{
    try{
        if(work.get()){
            appMode.setGraphic(light);
        }else{
            System.out.println("fail");
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You Can use this instead 

Platform.rynLater({Boolean val=false;
                try{
                    light=new ImageView();
                    lightImg=new Image(App.class.getResourceAsStream("iconindicators/light.png"));
                    light.setImage(lightImg);
                    val=true;
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    System.out.println(ex);
                } if(val)){
        appMode.setGraphic(light);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Failed.");
    }})
```

Comment: What does this function do? Does the intended code run immediately on new thread or does it run in future on Main thread?

Comment: The code will run in another background thread.